# How the mail notifications are working in Odoo14 for the Leave application, approval/rejection?

Tags: odoo-14

While applying, approving/rejecting the leave sometimes the emails are sent from the odoo14 system, but there is no mail template or mail sending functionality found in the leave module. Does anyone know how it's working? Images of the mail are below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the post message for leave acceptance [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/hr_holidays/models/hr_leave.py#L989) and for leave refusing [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/hr_holidays/models/hr_leave.py#L1125)

The `message_post` method respect the user's preference. If the user changes the notification option from the user preferences in user form to `Handle by Odoo`   rather than `Handle by Emails`,the user will not receive emails; instead, they will receive notifications in Odoo's UI.

Comment: I have checked that already and that is not where the mail is sending. I tried changing the content there and its not working. It's to post the message in the record history as the mail message.

Comment: I see, Please check if you have a custom automated action or a custom module for that purpose because I can't find any email body like that and it looks a custom.

Comment: Hi Waleed, thanks for your support. Unfortunately that is also not working. I have checked the same and changed the preference to Handle By Odoo and still the mail is sending from the system with the approve, reject and View time off buttons. That mail is from the odoo system itself as I haven't done any custom template in any of the custom modules used.